# How to dial a Number in C# windows universal 10

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

Hy in win8 you can

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "2065550123";
phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Gage";
phoneCallTask.Show();
```

but in Win 10 universal apps you have to use

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls;
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI(PhoneNumber, DisplayName);
```

and in the msdn dev network there is a PhoneCallManager Class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager.aspx

But when i add the Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls; i can't use the PhoneCallManager because there isn't any callmanager..

I activated the Phone Call Capabilities.

Visual Studio 2015
Windows Universal APP
c#
XAML
Thanks

Comment: I cant use the PhoneCallManager like in the code.. i got an err

Comment: How?
The PhoneCallManager could not be found in the namespace 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls'.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ms7MOh0.png

Comment: yes, but UniversalApiContract doesn't exist..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As your error states:

> The type name `PhoneCallManager` could not be found in the namespace `Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls`. This type has been forwarded to assembly `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime`. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

So you need to add a reference (see [MSDN: How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)) to the assembly [Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706155.aspx).

If you search the web for the "consider adding a reference...", [you will find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186156/windows-10-universal-app-type-exists-in-both-windows-foundation-universalapic) you need to reference the Windows 10 SDK, not the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK.

The reference you need to add for this assembly is under "Universal Windows" -> "Extensions" and is called "Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP".

Comment: @Tobias thanks, I've updated my answer with that. :)